# How to launch a second Application mentioned in Manifest when a button is clicked

Tags: android

How to start Activity OfferActivity in the second Application AppController defined in the Manifest on a button click, The second Application is mentioned in the Manifest file along with its activity , please provide code to start the activity on a button click.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kashif.gulzar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/shopping"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ListViewDemo"/>
    </application>
    <application 
        android:name="kashif.gulzar.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="kashif.gulzar.app.OfferActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Please provide code

Comment: Android does not use multiple `<application>` elements at this time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use only one `<application>` tag:

```
<application ...>
 <activity .../> 
 <activity .../>
 <activity .../>
</application>
```

And about your question. If your layout for `MainActivity` (I supppose it's activity_main.xml) contains `Button` with id `button1`, use this code in `OnCreate`:

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        if(button != null) 
        {
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OfferActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
         }
```